# AgGrid : Master / Details doesn't work when table has only one line

Tags: angular, ag-grid, master-detail

I have an issue with the Master / Details feature of AgGrid Angular

**Context :**
I have a server-side table. When the table is initialized, it contacts my API for data.
The data is returned and contains a "childContainer" key.
If this key is not empty, the table considers the row as master, so the row details are contained in the "childContainer" attribute.

**Problem :**
The Master / Detail feature works perfectly except when the Master is the last row on the page.
When the Master is the last line on the page, I can click on the arrow to display the details and the table expands, but the details are not displayed.
However, if the Master is not the last line on the page, the function works normally. I can see the master's details.

I didn't get a console error and I have no investigative leads to find the source of this error.

**Screenshot :**
Below, a screenshot of my issue :
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help and your answers :-)

Comment: The dynamic row-detail would be controlled by `isRowMaster`. And looking at an example on their docs, it seems to be working. Are you able to add your code to the question?